Como utilizar a estrutura de dados em Portugol?
Estou tendo que desenvolver um algoritmo em portugol por conta da faculdade, porém ao criar o algoritmo não estou conseguindo criar uma estrutura para determinado produto. segue exemplo
estrutura Produto {
        cadeia nome
        inteiro quantidade
        real preco
        cadeia validade
    }

Seria possível estar usando a estrutura em Portugol?
Tentei criar uma estrutura de dados de um produto achando que seria possível utilizar na linguagem Portugol Studio, porém não está  sendo aceita

Em PortugolStudio tem um issue aberto no github: https://github.com/UNIVALI-LITE/Portugol-Studio/issues/559

Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.
